# Populate fields from database based on user input SQL

Tags: php, sql, forms, populate, auto-populate

I have a form where the user inputs their ID and this then populates their name from a database? There is a whole form I just copied the relevant parts and the sql below.

```
User ID: <input value="User ID" name="user_id">

$sql = "SELECT user_firstname, user_surname FROM users_tbl WHERE xxxx = users_tbl.user_id"
$result = pg_query($sql);
```

I have made it this far, but im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like ...

page1.php

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
User ID: <input name="user_id" value="User ID">
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

page2.php

```
$id = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['user_id'] );
$sql = "SELECT `user_firstname`, `user_surname` FROM `users_tbl `WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1";
...
```

Comment: I could also use Ajax I guess

Comment: indeed, depends on what will change on the page. if only a few elements on page change (like "sign in / register" becomes "account / sign out"), or nothing at all, ajax is the better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter GET or POST form variables. So the right way would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_firstname, user_surname FROM users_tbl WHERE users_tbl.user_id= ".$_POST['user_id'];
$result = pg_query($sql);
```

Also don't forget to filter POST and GET variables from sql injections

Comment: This is how i thought it would be solved. I guess the form has to be sent first? which will then place the fields into the submit button variables from the form?

Comment: Yes the form should be sent first. All the form variables will be placed in $_POST variable